# JQuery to Vue js

Tags: javascript, jquery, vuejs2

How to convert this code to vue2js im newbie in vue

```
var $btnMenu = $('.menu-mobile'),
            $hideMenu = $('.hide-menu');

        $btnMenu.on('click', function () {
            $header.toggleClass('active');

            if ($header.hasClass('active')) {
                $hideMenu.addClass('active');
            }
            else {
                $hideMenu.removeClass('active');
            }
        });
        $hideMenu.on('click', function () {
            $header.removeClass('active');
            $hideMenu.removeClass('active');
        });

        $('.menu-item-has-children', '.main-menu').on('click', ' > a', function (e) {
            var ww = $(window).width();

            if (ww <=991) {
                var $parent = $(e.target).closest('.menu-item-has-children');
                e.preventDefault();
                $('>.sub-menu', $parent).slideToggle(400);
            }
        });
```

Comment: You need to provide more details when asking a question. What did you try?

Comment: simply i just wanna to hide and show when i click the button using vue, but add class in tag id

Comment: That's pretty easy with Vue.js. Take a look at [the docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html).

Answer (score 0):

Well, impossible to answer without more details. What's the context ?

I think you should refer to the well written [Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/) and learn the basics, all of what you need is here.